# 'Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.' ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller

This question has been asked so many times, but none seem to solve my problem. I am creating a rating system and I can add records but when I go to view the details of the record, I get a `System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.'` error. This is the line of code that is causing the error:

```cs
var comments = db.ArticlesComments.Where(d => d.ArticleId.Equals(id.Value)).ToList();
```

Here is the complete code:

```cs
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Article article = db.Articles.Find(id);
    if (article == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.ArticleId = id.Value;

    var comments = db.ArticlesComments.Where(d => d.ArticleId.Equals(id.Value)).ToList();
    ViewBag.Comments = comments;

    var ratings = db.ArticlesComments.Where(d => d.ArticleId.Equals(id.Value)).ToList();
    if (ratings.Count() > 0)
    {
        var ratingSum = ratings.Sum(d => d.Rating.Value);
        ViewBag.RatingSum = ratingSum;
        var ratingCount = ratings.Count();
        ViewBag.RatingCount = ratingCount;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.RatingSum = 0;
        ViewBag.RatingCount = 0;
    }

    return View(article);
}
```

Comment: Which type has `ArticleId`? And why not just use "=="?

Comment: Any reason why this `d.ArticleId.Equals(id.Value))` cannot be `d.ArticleId == id.Value)`

Comment: @JamesS that worked!! any reason why?

Comment: When `==` is used against an expression of type `object` it defaults to `ReferenceEquals` whereas `.Equals` is a virtual method so the overridden version will be used.